# Display Predefined Date in Datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, datepicker

Goal:
Display specified date in the datepicker based on available date from the database.
For example,  I have date "2015-04-30", "2015-05-15", and "2015-05-16" in the database and these three date should only displayed in the datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Question:
I tried to find any solution but I failed. I don't know what to do?

Information:
*I retrieve the dates' value as a string "150430". The default value I retrieve is datetype datetime. Totally, it is two different parameter.
*https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
*I'm using ASP.net MVC and Bootstrap

Comment: you can use as in example: http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/1389/

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this, only available dates will select other will unselectable.
check in already given example.

You can add into the array as:

```
var availableDates = ["9-5-2015","14-5-2015","15-5-2015"];
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/1389/

Comment: Do you know how to test if this datepicker works in different and older web browser?

Comment: you can user IE tester tools to check in IE, for safari you can use developer agent option. and chrome is user specific, try multiple user accounts and install different version for each user.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the documentation:

[image]

So you can basically do this:

```
var availableDates = ["30-4-2015","15-5-2015","16-5-2015"];

$('#datePicker').datepicker({ 
      beforeShowDay: isDateAvailabele 
});
```

And construct the function to return `[true, "", ""]` or `[false, "", ""]` depending if the date is to be presented.

```
function isDateAvailabele(date) { 
      // check your date formatting with the dates in the array 
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to test if this datepicker works in different and older web browser?

Comment: It depends on which version of Jquery UI you are using. Read this: https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/